# FontForge / Mac's Font Book - Rearrange font family order

Tags: fonts, font-forge

Is there a way to change the font weight's order through Font Forge? WhenI downloaded Aktiv Grotesk, each font weight was its own font. I used Font Forge to merge them all into one font family.

[image]

Comment: Technically the license of your font forbids doing this in most cases.